# One-dimensional, two-dimensional, three-dimensional, four-dimensional space, and, in general, $\Bbb R^n$

Tags: general-topology, physics, intuition

Often with high school students I find myself confronted with the concept of one-dimensional ($\Bbb R$, where $(x)$ it is a coordinate of a straight line), two-dimensional $\Bbb R^2=\Bbb R\times \Bbb R$ (cartesian plane, $(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2$), three-dimensional $\Bbb R^3$ (like triple coordinates in the space $(x,y,z)$), four-dimensional (our dimension) $\Bbb R^4$ with $(x,y,z,t)$ where $t$ is the time, and $t>0$, and $\Bbb R^n$ spaces.

What idea could be valid to better motivate the meaning of $\Bbb R^n$?

Comment: Well... You can see $\Bbb R^4$ as a system where you want to describe a simultaneously the position of a flying airplane and of a train on some railway.

Comment: @Gae.S. I am agree with you.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_space

Comment: @downvoter: what is the reason for a downvote like a thunderbolt?

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin Thank you very much for your support but I cannot explain the space of the phases, but a few simple and intuitive examples: they are simply 14 to 19 years old.

Comment: For me, by far, the best "description" is the one peek-a-boo described. Think of a point in $\Bbb R^4$ as a point in $\Bbb R^3$ along with its temperature. A point in $\Bbb R^5$ is a point in $\Bbb R^3$ along with a temperature and color. Etc.

Comment: @ElliotG Can you ask a favour, kindness? Can you convert your comment with an answer? It is good also your observation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you have $N$ particles, and to describe each of their location, you need a point in $\Bbb{R}^3$. So, $\xi_1= (x_1, y_1, z_1)\in\Bbb{R}^3$ is the point where the first particle is situated, $\xi_2 = (x_2,y_2,z_2)\in \Bbb{R}^3$ is where the second is situated and so on up to $\xi_N$. If you want to talk about the whole system simultaneously, you need to keep track of everything! You need to know $(\xi_1, \dots, \xi_N)= ((x_1, y_1, z_1), \dots, (x_N,y_N,z_N))$. How much information is there here? Just count: we have $x_1,y_1,z_1, \dots, x_N,y_N,z_N$, which is a total of $3N$ numbers (i.e we're not dealing with $\Bbb{R}$, or $\Bbb{R}^2$ or $\Bbb{R}^3$, but we're dealing with $\Bbb{R}^{3N}$).

So, depending on how much "information" you want to keep track of, you need a higher dimensional space. So, even though we are accustomed to a 3-dimensional world, it makes a lot of sense (to me anyway) to start dealing with $\Bbb{R}^n$ generally for any integer $n\geq 1$.

Comment: I ask you a kindness, could you explain it more simply by adding even the most trivial details? With all my heart I appreciate your effort, but I still don't understand your answer. Thank you and excuse me.

Comment: @Sebastiano what is it you need explaining?

Comment: Why do you use $\Bbb{R}^{3N}$ and could be a black-hole a space $\Bbb R^n$? I don't know if the tags are right.

Comment: @Sebastiano it's not at all clear to me what you're asking here. I think I've written the answer to the best of my ability. If you need something clarified you're going to have to ask a much more specific question about what it is you didn't understand here.

Comment: I have understood before, thinking. :-( Perfect!!! But I have not understood these downvotes....I try to improve my knowledge and you get massacred. I don't know. Thank you very much.

Comment: Use $n = 0$ when you want to "keep track of" no information at all ;-)

Answer (score 3):

As requested from the comments:

For me, by far, the best "description" is the one peek-a-boo described. Think of a point in $\Bbb R^4$ as a point in $\Bbb R^3$ along with its temperature. A point in $\Bbb R^5$ is a point in $\Bbb R^3$ along with a temperature and color. Etc.

In theory, you can keep going using pressure, density, intensity, etc.

I'm not sure this will help anyone actually solve problems, but it's a nice mindset to have for an introductory multi-dimensional calculus class, for example. Often times those courses mostly deal with $\Bbb R^3$ and $\Bbb R^4$, and I remember being comforted by having *some* mental image for $\Bbb R^4$.

Maybe this is off-topic now, but I remember being frustrated for a while because I couldn't "visualize" $\Bbb R^4$. Now I'm of the mindset that nobody can, or rather that "visualizing $\Bbb R^4$" is meaningless because we live and evolved in three apparent dimensions. So I don't think one can do much better than describe $\Bbb R^n$ in terms of a more familiar space, and it might help new students to know that they aren't necessarily lacking some special intuition that everyone else has.

Comment: +1 Your last paragraph hit the point which I was thinking of, but forgot to mention explicitly. Trying to visualize $\Bbb{R}^n$ for $n\geq 4$ is something which I certainly can't do (no matter how much I lie/trick myself when studying differential geometry:) ) but just because we can't *visualize* something, it doesn't mean we're at a dead-end, because we can certainly come up with new ways of *thinking* about it (like a huge space of parameters)